# Python select a file from a list

Tags: python, list, parsing

I have a folder that contains several log file that I will parse with python.

I would show the list of file contained into a folder like:

- [1] FileName1.log
- [2] FileName2.log

And then the user can choose the right file writing the file list number.

For instance, to parse the file "FileName2.log" the user press 2.

In my script I can show the list of file but I don't now how to pick up a file from a list by index.

This is my script

```
import os
import sys

items = os.listdir("D:/Logs")

fileList = []

for names in items:
    if names.endswith(".log"):
        fileList.append(names)

cnt = 0
for fileName in fileList:
    sys.stdout.write( "[%d] %s\n\r" %(cnt, fileName) )
    cnt = cnt + 1


fileName = raw_input("\n\rSelect log file [0 -" + str(cnt) + " ]: ")
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Hint: use enumerate to have a more pythonic and readable code `for cnt, fileName in enumerate(fileList):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the names in an array like this:

```
fileList = ['FileName1.log','FileName2.log']
```

you can pull them out by using their index (remember that arrarys are 0-indexed) so `fileList[0]` would be `'FileName1.log'` 
when you ask for the user to input a number (eg 0, 1, 2) you would then use that number to get the file you want. like this:

```
fileToRead=fileList[userInput]
```

if you asked for 1,2,3 you would need to use `userInput-1` to make sure it is correctly 0-indexed.
then you open the file you now have:

```
f=open(fileToRead, 'r')
```

you can read more about open [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Thanks! I solved my problem. I think that is not possible to select a list element from its index. I think that is possible only on tuple.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os
import sys

items = os.listdir("D:/Logs")

fileList = [name for name in items if name.endswith(".log")]

for cnt, fileName in enumerate(fileList, 1):
    sys.stdout.write("[%d] %s\n\r" % (cnt, fileName))

choice = int(input("Select log file[1-%s]: " % cnt))
print(fileList[choice])
```

you own version of code with few modifications, hope this solves your purpose

Comment: off by one in fileList[choice] but otherwise kudos

Answer (score 1):

If `fileList` is a list of files, and `fileName` is the user input, you can reference the file the user chose by using the following:

```
fileList[fileName]
```

Comment: Since the log file name is very long, I would avoid the user to digit the entire name of file. I would select the file with the index of file list.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what this code is doing. The user just needs to type the index.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
import os

dirpath = r"D:\Logs"  # the directory that contains the log files
prefix = "FileName"
fpaths = glob.glob(os.path.join(dirpath, "{}*.log".format(prefix)))  # get all the log files
fpaths.sort(key=lambda fname: int(fname.split('.',1)[0][len(prefix):]))  # sort the log files by number

print("Select a file to view:")
for i,fpath in enumerate(fpaths, 1):
    print("[{}]: {}".format(i, os.path.basename(fpath)))

choice = int(input("Enter a selection number: "))  # assuming valid inputs
choice -= 1  # correcting for python's 0-indexing

print("You have chosen", os.path.basename(fpaths[choice]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add in the end something like this...

```
sys.stdout.write(fileList[int(fileName)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexing in python as in many other languages starts from 0. Try this:

```
import os
import sys

items = os.listdir("D:/Logs")

fileList = []

for names in items:
    if names.endswith(".log"):
        fileList.append(names)

cnt = 0
for fileName in fileList:
    sys.stdout.write( "[%d] %s\n\r" %(cnt, fileName) )
    cnt = cnt + 1


fileName = int(raw_input("\n\rSelect log file [0 - " + str(cnt - 1) + "]: "))
print(fileList[fileName])
```

You need to cast input from `raw_input()` to int. And then you can use the obtained number as index for your list. 0 is the first file, 1 is the second file etc.